# Tensorflow ModuleNotFoundErrors and Failed to load the native runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to run something using tensorflow and have been running into a few issues. I'm new to tensorflow and not quite sure what I'm missing nor how to get them running.

Hope this error is enough information.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "scorch.py", line 5, in <module>
        import tensorflow as tf
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import *
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
      File "C:\Users\Soss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

    See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

    for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
    above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: _See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions._ Did you? How are you running TensorFlow, how did you install it, we need more information than this... Also, the formatting of the error message looked off. I tried to fix it, but it's still not perfect, so you might need to take a look yourself.

Comment: I went through the solutions but honestly not 100% sure what is effecting this still. I'm not very knowledgeable in this field. I installed tensorflow through "pip install tensorflow". The formatting just wouldn't paste how the source was. Tried googling how to properly format, and it still wouldn't work so I manually indented the errors myself messing it up slightly. Thanks for asking these questions as it may help me or someone else in the future. Also sorry if this still isn't enough information. I'm lost lol.Going to mess with this today and possibly try re-installing tensor.

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? For something like TensorFlow, I would probably recommend just using Conda, especially if you’re on Windows.